# Initialize radio button as checked from preferences saved in PhoneApplicationService

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button

Iam developing a windows phone application. I have a preference page which loads with defaults value all the time. I used a `PhoneApplicationService` to save Name property of the radio buttons that have been checked to preserve the value to be used for next time.

In the constructor class of the preference page how should i code to initiate with the name of the radio buttons which are saved in `PhoneApplicationService`

```
<RadioButton Content="Black" Name="ic_black" GroupName="gColor" Click="icChange" />
<RadioButton Content="Blue" GroupName="gColor" Name="ic_blue" Click="icChange" />
<RadioButton Content="Brown" GroupName="gColor" Name="ic_brown" Click="icChange" />
<RadioButton Content="Gray" GroupName="gColor" Name="ic_gray"  Click="icChange" />
```

The Above code is the xaml for preference page. icChange method gets the name of the radio button and saves it in `PhoneApplicationService.State["color"]`

```
{
            InitializeComponent();
            object prefs;
            string temp;
            if (prefs.State.TryGetValue("color", out prefs))
            {
                temp =  prefs.ToString();
                //the name of the radio button to be checked is the variable temp..
                //code to initialize the correct radio button from prefs
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose something like the following, even if it is not the best:

```
temp =  prefs.ToString();  
if(ic_black.Name == temp) ic_black.IsChecked = true;
else if(ic_blue.Name == temp) ic_blue.IsChecked = true;
else if(ic_brown.Name == temp) ic_brown.IsChecked = true;
else if(ic_gray.Name == temp) ic_gray.IsChecked = true;
else //Do the default case
```